# SQL JOIN COUNT and SELECT in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I am new to SQL and trying to join 2 tables to add a count :

First Table: Slot, Second Table : Reservation (with column slot_id), so to count the reservations associated to a given slot

```
 group_by slots.id
 count reservations.id
```

I would like to join the user of the slot (user_id column in Slot table) with joins(:user), with his email, but I can't use this select because of the group_by

```
select('slots.*,  count(reservations.id) as res_count, users.email as email')
```

How can I join the user with his email and still perform the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned anything about the relationship between user and slot, but assuming each slot can only have one user, you should just add the email to the group by statement also:

```
select
    s.id as slot_id,
    u.email,
    count(reservation.id) as num_reservations
from Slot s
left join Reservation r
    on s.reservation_id = r.id --assuming this is the key
left join Users u
    on s.user_id = u.id
group_by slot.id, u.email;
```